# Is it possible for a Blazor WebAssembly PWA to run a local desktop app on the user's file system?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, blazor, webassembly

I really doubt it but I figure it never hurts to ask... what I want to do is create a game matchmaking site that is capable of launching the actual games from within the web app. If not I guess I can create a client/server desktop app or something instead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the PWA sandbox prohibits it.

You could try building an Electron app that runs your Blazor WASM - https://github.com/aspnet/AspLabs/tree/master/src/ComponentsElectron

Or you could give the following link a try. It does something similar, but doesn't bundle the browser in order to reduce size - https://github.com/steveSandersonMS/BlazorDesktop

Steve Sanderson wrote a pretty informative blog on it
https://blog.stevensanderson.com/2019/11/01/exploring-lighter-alternatives-to-electron-for-hosting-a-blazor-desktop-app/

Comment: Hmm, @Peter-Morris would it be possible to launch an app using a link? In the same way Github does for the desktop version: e.g. `<a href="x-github-client://openRepo/https://github.com/repopathhere">` ? Obviously the app would need to be registered and the browser will prompt to confirm the action.

Comment: If it works in a browser then it should work. Make sure you use NavigationManager to perform the navigation with `true` as the `forceLoad` parameter